# Chrome - Script tag isn't blocking

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In the following example:

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<script src="2.js"></script>
<img src="FDA.PNG" alt="" />
```

The first  tag should block the parsing of the html, but according to the timeline, it's not.

[image]

All the files are loading at the same time, why?

Comment: Because that's how Chrome is designed? What's the problem? The JS will block when it runs. It shouldn't matter that resources are fetched concurrently.

Comment: ...if you wanted to guarantee that the `img` or some other resource is not fetched until the scripts have run, then create it dynamically in a script that comes after the others.

Comment: I don't see any reason for downvoting this question. It's a somewhat basic question if you're familiar with how browsers do this stuff; it's a completely understandable question if you aren't, and probably a bit tricky to research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scripts are **executed** in the order they appear in the HTML (unless you use the `async` or `defer` attributes). Browsers are perfectly welcome, however, to **download** them in any order they like, including in parallel, and including in parallel with other resources such as CSS files and images they find in the HTML. This is a Good Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>, it helps our pages load faster. Scripts downloaded before it's their turn to run are held until it's their turn.

> The first tag should block the parsing of the html...

Not the parsing. Just the building of the DOM and execution of the scripts.